# Logging Security Protocol for C# HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, tls1.2, .net-4.6

I have a daemon that makes outbound WebRequests based on information from a database. It is written in C# using .net 4.6. I have modified the initialization of my process to set:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

This all works correctly. I now would like to add some logging to see what various security protocols I'm using on the outbound connections. I'm thinking, "established tls 1.2 connection to https://www.google.com"

My problem is at the level of HttpWebRequest, I don't appear to be able to get information about the SecurityProtocol. I can get things about the server certificate:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateRemoteCertificate);
```

So inspecting the certificate, I can log things like:

```
FriendlyName    "sha256RSA" string
Value   "1.2.840.113549.1.1.11” string //I do not believe this version number corresponds to the TLS version, I believe this is the version of the SHA256 encryption algorithm.
```

Is it possible to get information about the security protocol? Also, is it possible to get access to the underlying SslStream object inside the HttpWebRequest?

Comment: I tested with one my programs that uses authenticated https requests. I know for a fact that it uses TLS 1.1. Looking at the HttpWebRequest object, I see that the ProtocolVersion variable is set to 1.1. The information you are looking for might be stored there. I would test with TLS 1.2 and SSL 3 to validate. Edit: Think I might be wrong. This is the HTTP protocol version. Will dig deeper.

Comment: Yea its the http protocol version not the underlying security protocol. [MSDN ProtocolVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.protocolversion(v=vs.110).aspx)